# SQL Stuck in Query how to get the right data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In this Query i am trying to grab values (mainly r.dpq) where **the price are the same** for territory in **31 , 41 , 125 , 201** where the price should be **922** and for **all other territories the price should be 216**

The query grabs indeed products that have the price 216 in the territories 31 , 41 , 125 , 201 but not in the other territories i guess the error is in here but i dont know how to correct it

```
rte.TerritoryId not in (31,41,201,125) and rte.PriceCodeId=216 and rte.PartnerTerritoryId is null
```

Here is the full query

```
select r.dpq, r.OwningTerritoryId , r.id from Release r
inner join ReleaseTerritory rt on rt.ReleaseId=r.Id
inner join ReleaseTerritoryPrice rtp on rtp.ReleaseId=r.Id
where exists (
select * from ReleaseTerritoryPrice rtp31, ReleaseTerritoryPrice rtp201,ReleaseTerritoryPrice rtp41,ReleaseTerritoryPrice rtp125,
ReleaseTerritory rt69 , ReleaseTerritoryPrice rte
where 
rtp31.ReleaseId=r.Id and rtp201.ReleaseId=r.Id and rtp41.ReleaseId=r.Id and rtp125.ReleaseId=r.Id and rt69.ReleaseId=r.Id and 
rte.ReleaseId=r.Id and 
rtp31.TerritoryId=31 and rtp201.TerritoryId=201 and rtp41.TerritoryId=41 and rtp125.TerritoryId=125 and 
rtp31.PriceCodeId=rtp201.PriceCodeId and rtp201.PriceCodeId=rtp41.PriceCodeId and rtp41.PriceCodeId=rtp125.PriceCodeId and 
rt69.TerritoryId=69 and 
rtp31.PriceCodeId=922 and 
rt69.IsLocked=0 and 
rte.TerritoryId not in (31,41,201,125) and rte.PriceCodeId=216 and rte.PartnerTerritoryId is null
) and r.OwningTerritoryId in (201,200)
group by r.dpq , r.OwningTerritoryId , r.Id
order by r.OwningTerritoryId
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: Did any of our answers assist you in resolving your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the final part of your where clause to be:

```
AND (
       (rte.TerritoryId IN (31,41,201,125) AND rte.PriceCodeId = 922)     
        OR
       (rte.TerritoryId NOT IN (31,41,201,125) AND rte.PriceCodeId = 216)
    )
```

**Note** the additional brackets at the start and end of the statement - these are important to keep the OR localized to this statement only rather than nullifying the rest of the `AND` statements in your full query.

You must also **remove** this statement from your WHERE clause as it is restricting the results to these 4 territories only

```
rtp31.TerritoryId=31 and rtp201.TerritoryId=201 
and rtp41.TerritoryId=41 and rtp125.TerritoryId=125
```

Answer (score 1):

I think filter you mentioned is not as your requirment. It may be like

```
(rte.TerritoryId not in (31,41,201,125) and rte.PriceCodeId=216) or
(rte.TerritoryId not (31,41,201,125) and rte.PriceCodeId=922)
```